# Spring Boot & Thymeleaf: list of links

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Java/Spring Boot web app here using Thymeleaf as the templating engine.

My bean:

```
public class InventoryItem {

  private String modelNumber;
  private String name;

  // getters, setters and ctors omitted for brevity
  
}
```

My Spring controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/inventory")
public class InventoryController {

  @GetMapping("/{inventoryId}")
  public String viewInventory(@PathVariable("inventoryId") String inventoryId, Model model) {

      List<InventoryItem> inventory = getSomehow(inventoryId);
      model.addAttribute("inventory", inventory);

      return "inventory";

  }
  
}
```

And a snippet from the `inventory.html` file that Thymeleaf must template:

```
<div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
    <div class="panel-body">Inventory Items</div>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="item :${inventory}" th:text="${item.name}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

At runtime this produces a nice unordered list of inventory item names.

What I want now is to make this an unordered list of hyperlinks (`<a/>`) such that the rendered HTML looks like so:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/inventoryDetails/12345">Goose</a></li>
  <li><a href="/inventoryDetails/23456">Duck</a></li>
  <!-- etc. -->
</ul>
```

Where `12345` and `23456` are `InventoryItem#modelNumbers` and where `Goose` and `Duck` are `InventoryItem#names`. I've asked the Google Gods high and low and cannot find a working example of using Thymeleaf to render a list (ordered/unordered alike) of hyperlinks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work ...

```
<div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
    <div class="panel-body">Inventory Items</div>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="item :${inventory}">
            <a th:href="@{/inventoryDetails/{modelNumber}(modelNumber=${item.modelNumber})}" th:text="${item.name}">Goose</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you would like to get more information on how to work with [Link URLs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls), follow Thymeleaf documentation.